# Issue Retrieving JSON Data from website

Tags: ios, json, swift

I am trying to print JSON data to the screen but whenever I run the application, the program crashes. I have searched stack overflow but cannot find my issue.

```
    var url = NSURL(string: "https://alpha-api.app.net/stream/0/posts/stream/global")!
    var requestURL = NSURLRequest(URL: url)

    NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(requestURL, queue: NSOperationQueue(), completionHandler:{ (response: NSURLResponse!, data: NSData!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
        var json = NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers, error: nil) as [NSMutableDictionary]
        println(json)
        println("Got data from \(requestURL.URL)")
    })
```

Comment: Are there any debug messages? Error messages? Stack trace????

Comment: Two points. Never say my program crashed without posting the actual error message -- don't paraphrase, post the actual message. Second, whenever a method contains an error parameter, USE IT! Don't set it to nil.

Comment: The error message comes up in the assembly code stating: thread 3:EXC_BREAKPOINT(code=I386_BPT,subcode=0x0)

Comment: And there you just posted the useless bit of information and left all the good bits out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A few things I would personally do, see if these will make it work better:

```
var request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: passedURL)
    NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(request, queue: NSOperationQueue.mainQueue()) {
        (response, data, error) in

        println(response)
        println(data)
        println(error)
        if error == nil {
            if let HTTPResponse = response as? NSHTTPURLResponse {
                let statusCode = HTTPResponse.statusCode
                if statusCode == 200 {
                    println("success")
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

If that doesn't work do these steps:

First, check if the link works. If it does, I'd just try printing the error, data and response to the logs before doing anything. If those are clear, try printing the data without turning it into JSON and see if it works.

Comment: It does print success for me; however, when I try to create a json object using NSJSONSerialization directly after the success statement, the error message displays: thread 3:EXC_BREAKPOINT(code=I386_BPT,subcode=0x0)

Comment: It will probably be something different then: what thread is highlighted? If it highlights the beginning of AppDelegate, you may have elements in the Interface Builder that are connected to IBOutlets that once existed and you deleted.

Comment: Your code works perfectly now. It wast just the JSON I was using online. Thank you